# can a systemd service be run at multiple run levels

Tags: systemd

I have a sysv style init file for a service being used in centos 7.1
When the system boot up, the systemd generates a service file and it
seems to be enabled for both level 2 and level 3.

I have following questions:
1) Can the service be started twice at each run level ? [How can I prevent
it if it can start]
2) How can I check at which run-level the currently executing service
was started on ?
Thanks
Arvind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on your service. If your service is an active service then starting it will not do anything. You can find if your service is an active service or not by running "`systemctl status yourservice.service`". In case your service is not active, you can tell systemd to treat it as an active service even after it quits. The directive for this is `RemainAfterExit=` (https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#RemainAfterExit=).

To find out which run level your service has been started by you need to look at the "systemctl show yourservice.service" output. Look at what is listed on `WantedBy=` or `RequiredBy=` fields.